# Is it correct to use an indirect object after “suggest”?

Tags: indirect-objects

Is it correct to use an indirect object after “suggest”?

1. Our neighbor suggested to my mom to take us to the new public swimming pool.
   [taking us]
2. The doctor suggested to my mom that I should do exercises to lose weight.

Comment: Have you searched for uses of "suggest to"? What did you find? What are you still unsure about? Please edit your question to show us what you already know so we don't "reinvent the wheel".

Comment: I doubt it is an error, but your first example looks awkward. “suggested [that] my Mom take us to X” is far more idiomatic in American English. Your second example is fine.

Comment: Our neighbor suggested [that] my mom take us to the new public swimming pool.
Now, in this new option that you give, who the neighbor suggested the idea to? To my mom or to us?
What about that? 
Our neighbor suggested to my mom that she take us to the new public swimming pool.
Is it ok, awkward, or redundant?